# Chrome extensions - Other ways to read response bodies than chrome.devtools.network?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to read (not modify) the response body for all requests that match some pattern in a Chrome extension. I'm currently using [chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.network.html#event-onRequestFinished), which gives you a `Request` object with a `getContent()` method. This works just fine, but of course requires the devtools to be open for the extension to work. Ideally the extension would be a popup, but [chrome.webRequest.onCompleted](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onCompleted) doesn't seem to give access to the response body. There is a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058) to allow the webRequest API to *edit* response bodies - but can webRequest even read them? If not, is there any other way to read response bodies outside of devtools extensions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The feature request you linked](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058) to implies that there is no support for reading either:

> Unfortunately, this request is not trivial. (...) Regarding reading the Response Body: This is challenging from a performance perspective. (...) So overall, this is just not easy to achieve...

So, no, there doesn't seem to be a way for an extension to access network response bodies, except for devtools.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I did

1. I used the `chrome.webRequest` & `requestBody` to get the post requests body
2. I used a `decoder` the parse the body into a string

Here is an example

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        if(details.method == "POST")
        // Use this to decode the body of your post
            var postedString = decodeURIComponent(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,
                                      new Uint8Array(details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes)));
           console.log(postedString)

    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "requestBody"]
);
```

Comment: The question is about response bodies, not request bodies.

Answer (score -5):

If you have the this pattern of requests you can run something like that in your       *background.html* file:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://example.com/" + yourStringForPattern, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      var body = xhr.responseText;
      // call some function to do something with the html body

    }
   }
   xhr.send();
```

Comment: This just shows how to make a request.  The OP is asking how to monitor the response bodies of any requests the browser makes.  AFAIK chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished is still the only way to get bodies and requires the debugger to be open.