# Chrome Extension - How to get HTTP Response Body?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

It seems to be difficult problem (or impossible??).
I want to get and read HTTP Response, caused by HTTP Request in browser, under watching Chrome Extension background script.
We can get HTTP Request Body in this way

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(data){
    // data contains request_body
},{'urls':[]},['requestBody']);
```

I also checked these stackoverflows

- [Chrome extensions - Other ways to read response bodies than chrome.devtools.network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393638/chrome-extensions-other-ways-to-read-response-bodies-than-chrome-devtools-netw)
- [Chrome extension to read HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939467/chrome-extension-to-read-http-response)

Is there any clever way to get HTTP Response Body in Chrome Extension?

Comment: There's no general method. It's only possible for specific use cases.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I can't find better way then this anwser.

[Chrome extension to read HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939467/chrome-extension-to-read-http-response)

The answer told how to get  **response headers** and display in another page.But there is no body info in the response obj(see [event-responseReceived](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.0/network#event-responseReceived)). If you want to get response **body**  without another page, try this.

```
var currentTab;
var version = "1.0";

chrome.tabs.query( //get current Tab
    {
        currentWindow: true,
        active: true
    },
    function(tabArray) {
        currentTab = tabArray[0];
        chrome.debugger.attach({ //debug at current tab
            tabId: currentTab.id
        }, version, onAttach.bind(null, currentTab.id));
    }
)


function onAttach(tabId) {

    chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ //first enable the Network
        tabId: tabId
    }, "Network.enable");

    chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(allEventHandler);

}


function allEventHandler(debuggeeId, message, params) {

    if (currentTab.id != debuggeeId.tabId) {
        return;
    }

    if (message == "Network.responseReceived") { //response return 
        chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
            tabId: debuggeeId.tabId
        }, "Network.getResponseBody", {
            "requestId": params.requestId
        }, function(response) {
            // you get the response body here!
            // you can close the debugger tips by:
            chrome.debugger.detach(debuggeeId);
        });
    }

}
```

I think it's useful enough for me and you can use `chrome.debugger.detach(debuggeeId)`to close the ugly tip.

sorry, mabye not helpful... ^ ^

Comment: use `--silent-debugger-extension-api` command line switch to  lunch the browser to get rid of yellow bar , it must be the first instance of the browser

Comment: I keep getting undefined for response, do you have any idea?

Comment: I found the reason is "No resource with given identifier found" (requestId of getResponseBody is wrong), but I have no idea why it is wrong :(

Comment: I made a content script from the above code, and added a console.log and alert in the response body part, but nothing happens. Where should the code be placed?

Comment: I'm getting the error cannot 'attach' to chrome://url. Anyway around this and only attach to specific urls?

Comment: is this ran from a background script or from a content script?

Comment: @evanjmg You can query the url if you put "tabs" in the permissions array in `manifest.json`.  In `chrome.tabs.query`, use
`function (tabArray) {
            currentTab = tabArray[0];
            if(!currentTab.url.startsWith("chrome:")){
                chrome.debugger.attach({ //debug at current tab
                    tabId: currentTab.id
                }, version, onAttach.bind(null, currentTab.id));
            }
        }`

Comment: hello! were you able to catch all the requests this way? I wrote a script to catch all requests, it works fine with iframes, but not all requests are there..

Comment: Hi, If any one need more commands to get network information follow this link https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network

Comment: Mindboggling. **why** is debugger needed for basic reading of the http body?

Answer (score 14):

There is now a way in a Chrome Developer Tools extension, and sample code can be seen here: [blog post](https://medium.com/better-programming/chrome-extension-intercepting-and-reading-the-body-of-http-requests-dd9ebdf2348b).

In short, here is an adaptation of his sample code:

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(request => {
  request.getContent((body) => {
    if (request.request && request.request.url) {
      if (request.request.url.includes('facebook.com')) {

         //continue with custom code
         var bodyObj = JSON.parse(body);//etc.
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: From the article itself: The drawback for this method is that we have to keep the Chrome DevTools open all the time because DevTools extensions are only activated when DevTools is open.

Answer (score 12):

This is definitely something that is not provided out of the box by the Chrome Extension ecosystem. But, I could find a couple of ways to get around this but both come with their own set of drawbacks.

The **first way** is:

1. Use a content script to inject our own custom script.
2. Use the custom script to extend XHR's native methods to read the response.
3. Add the response to the web page's DOM inside a hidden (not `display: none`) element.
4. Use the content script to read the hidden response.

The **second way** is to create a **DevTools extension** which is the only extension that provides an API to read each request.

I have penned down both the methods in a detailed manner in a blog post [here.](https://medium.com/@tarundugar1992/chrome-extension-intercepting-and-reading-the-body-of-http-requests-dd9ebdf2348b)

Let me know if you face any issues! :)

Comment: Your article doesn't say how to send response to the background page, because injecting 'chrome.runtime.sendMessage' doesn't work.

Comment: @Andrew ill check, the article was meant for just reading response body. Can I ask where you are using 'chrome.runtime.sendMessage'?

Comment: I was trying to use it inside that injected content script, but it (obviously) doesn't work. Article mentioned that 'you can pass to BG' so it would be good to know how you can do that.

Comment: @Andrew you can use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` inside a content script: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts. Probably, something else is going wrong.

Comment: You cannot use chrome messaging api inside injected script the way article injects it with a self running function. There is no messaging between that script and extension.

Comment: @Andrew yes, because the injected script is not the content script. The way you can achieve this is by using appending the data from the injected script to a DOM element and then using the content script to access that data by reading the corresponding DOM element. I hope this clears it up?

Comment: Yes, that's the way. Also the content will be added 'dynamically' so when content script tries to 'read it' this should be taken into account.

Comment: @Andrew true, for that you can call a function inside the content script continuously wrapped inside a requestIdleCallback to avoid the browser from crashing. The function would just check for the contents of the DOM element where we are going to append the intercepted data.

Comment: with the arrival of chrome extension manifest v3 and their restriction to inject JS inline scripts, what are the solutions now, looking into the future?

Answer (score 8):

To get a XHR **response** body you can follow the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134114/12304742).

To get a FETCH **response** body you can check **Solution 3** in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45425169/) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64961272/12304742). Both get the response body **without using chrome.debugger.**

In a nutshell, you need to inject the following function into the page from the content script using the same method used for the XHR requests.

```
const constantMock = window.fetch;
 window.fetch = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        constantMock.apply(this, arguments)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response) {
                    response.clone().json() //the response body is a readablestream, which can only be read once. That's why we make a clone here and work with the clone
                    .then( (json) => {
                        console.log(json);
                        //Do whatever you want with the json
                        resolve(response);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                        reject(response);
                    })
                }
                else {
                    console.log(arguments);
                    console.log('Undefined Response!');
                    reject(response);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                reject(response);
            })
    })
}
```

If **response.clone().json()** does not work, you can try **response.clone().text()**

Comment: The question is about interception of all requests from the page with extension. Your answer is about interception of own requests. Own requests with fetch, for example, could be processed with ".then" function easily.

Comment: @SergeyNN My answer is about interception of all requests. Read carefully and try to understand!

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: response is not defined` in catch

Answer (score 1):

I show my completed code if it can be some help. I added the underscore to get the request url, thanks

```
//background.js
import _, { map } from 'underscore';

var currentTab;
var version = "1.0";

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(activeTab => {
    currentTab&&chrome.debugger.detach({tabId:currentTab.tabId});
    currentTab = activeTab;
    chrome.debugger.attach({ //debug at current tab
        tabId: currentTab.tabId
    }, version, onAttach.bind(null, currentTab.tabId));
});

function onAttach(tabId) {
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ //first enable the Network
        tabId: tabId
    }, "Network.enable");
    chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(allEventHandler);
}

function allEventHandler(debuggeeId, message, params) {
    if (currentTab.tabId !== debuggeeId.tabId) {
        return;
    }
    if (message === "Network.responseReceived") { //response return
        chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
            tabId: debuggeeId.tabId
        }, "Network.getResponseBody", {
            "requestId": params.requestId
            //use underscore to add callback a more argument, passing params down to callback
        }, _.partial(function(response,params) {
            // you get the response body here!
            console.log(response.body,params.response.url);
            // you can close the debugger tips by:
            // chrome.debugger.detach(debuggeeId);
        },_,params));
    }
}
```

I also find there is a bug in chrome.debugger.sendCommand. If I have two requests with same URI but different arguments. such as:

- requests 1:https://www.example.com/orders-api/search?limit=15&offer=0
- requests 2:https://www.example.com/orders-api/search?limit=85&offer=15

The second one will not get the corrected responseBody, it will show:

```
Chrome Extension: "Unchecked runtime.lastError: {"code":-32000,"message":"No resource with given identifier found"}
```

But I debugger directly in background devtools, it get the second one right body.

```
chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId:2},"Network.getResponseBody",{requestId:"6932.574"},function(response){console.log(response.body)})
```

So there is no problem with tabId and requestId.
Then I wrap the chrome.debugger.sendCommand with setTimeout, it will get the first and second responseBody correctly.

```
if (message === "Network.responseReceived") { //response return            
console.log(params.response.url,debuggeeId.tabId,params.requestId)
        setTimeout(()=>{
            chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
                tabId: debuggeeId.tabId
            }, "Network.getResponseBody", {
                "requestId": params.requestId
                //use underscore to add callback a more argument, passing params down to callback
            }, _.partial(function(response,params,debuggeeId) {
                // you get the response body here!
                console.log(response.body,params.response.url);
                // you can close the debugger tips by:
                // chrome.debugger.detach(debuggeeId);
            },_,params,debuggeeId));
        },800)
    
}
```

I think the setTimeout is not the perfect solution, can some one give help?
thanks.