# How get raw response body inside a Web Extension for Firefox 55?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I try to get the **raw response body** inside a Web Extension using Firefox 55.0.3.

Only "solutions" I have seen for now:

- Repeat the request (I absolutly don't want to repeat the request)
- Using Javascript to get `innerHTML` attribute of HTML tags such as `head` and `body` (tell me if I'm wrong, but with a solution like that I will not always have the whole content, for example I will get nothing in case of response without HTML. So it will never be the real raw response and in some case it will simply not work.)

Also, I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29845219/8237057) for Chrome (from 2015) using the debugger, but I wasn't able to do it with Firefox. This kind of solutions are interesting, I read Mozilla documentation about devtools but I didn't find a way of using the network tab of webtools interface with Javascript inside a Web Extension.

To give you more details, my goal is to intercept the full request and response from server (header and body). This is not a problem to do it, except for the response body.

Here an example of code to get the request body: (background script)

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    },
    {urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]},
    ["requestBody"]
)
```

Here some documentations that I used (there is more, but these links are all official):

- [Mozilla documentation about Web Extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions)

  - [Intercept HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests)
  - [webRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest)
  - [webRequest.onHeadersReceived](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onHeadersReceived)
  - [webRequest.onBeforeRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest)
  - [webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeSendHeaders)

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Examples) some examples of Web Extensions.

Any ideas, solutions or even explainations "why this is not possible" are welcome, thank you in advance for your time !

Cheers++

Comment: Which transfers are you trying to get the response to? AJAX? Actual web navigation (i.e. the base HTML page and resources, e.g `<script src="something">`)?

Comment: The raw headers and body of all HTTP(S) request and response. I don't care how is done the request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is now available, as of Firefox 57:
[`browser.webRequest.filterResponseData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/filterResponseData) allows you to add a listener via `browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` which receives, and allows you to modify the response.

You can see an example in [the Mozilla github webextensions-examples repo](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/master/http-response/background.js)

Comment: Awesome ! It works well, thank you very much to share this :)

Comment: unfortunately that example doesn't work for responses that are streamed or chunked because `filter.disconnect` is called before the rest of the response is processed. more advanced examples can be found here: https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/StreamFilter/ondata

Answer (score 4):

Firefox 57 is going to provide the API `browser.webRequest.filterResponseData`. This doesn't seem to be documented yet, but you can look through [bug 1255894](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1255894) for details.

Answer (score 3):

### Why is this not possible?

For the simple reason that WebRequest was ported over from Chrome extensions, where this is explicitly impossible.

Requests for such functionality ([to edit](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058), or just [to read](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487422)) has been around for a very long time (since 2011 and 2015 respectively); they are challenging from both the security perspective and technical perspective, however a [principal agreement that read access is a good idea](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/apps-dev/v176iCmRgSs/iM-72Evf8JgJ) is there.

However, it's simply not yet implemented. [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) has been doing some work in this direction but it's not done yet.

### Perhaps Firefox has a different implementation?

A cursory glance on Mozilla bugtracker doesn't find any bugs on providing this functionality. So, it's not likely that the implementation will diverge anytime soon.

### Any workarounds?

Well, only the debugger-level access can touch actual response data.

Since `debugger` is not implemented in the WebExtension platform, only a `devtools.network`-using extension can access it - and only while Dev Tools are open for the tab making said request, which is the main limitation of `devtools.*` APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I hope it will move forward and I will try to use `devtools.network` in the mean time.