# How would I search network traffic through a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension which intercepts network traffic and prints out as an alert. The first step I'm just trying to figure out how to first search the network traffic (from inspect), then from the list get the right xhr, and read the selected data from said xhr.

Comment: The console tool can do that, right? The 'Network' tab can show you the results as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome Extension - How to get HTTP Response Body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534771/chrome-extension-how-to-get-http-response-body)