# Electron: How to catch all the requests response from the main process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I want to get the response for all the requests that happen at my electron app from the main process.

[This image shows that the response I want to get would be at the Response tab and not at the Headers tab on Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYA1G.png).

I'm -not- using a `<webview>` tag, I'm using `mainWindow.loadURL()`.

---

This only returns the headers and some other stuff, but not the response

```js
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onCompleted({ urls: ['*://*/*'] }, function (details, callback) {
     console.log(details);
});
```

---

So to retrieve the response I've tried with this:

```js
try {
     mainWindow.webContents.debugger.attach('1.3')
} catch (err) {
     console.log('Debugger attach failed: ', err)
}

mainWindow.webContents.debugger.on('detach', (event, reason) => {
     console.log('Debugger detached due to: ', reason)
});

mainWindow.webContents.debugger.sendCommand('Network.enable');

session.defaultSession.webRequest.onCompleted({ urls: ['*://*/*'] }, function (details, callback) {
     mainWindow.webContents.debugger.sendCommand('Network.getResponseBody', { requestId: details.id.toString() }, function (body, body64) {
          console.log(body);
     });
});
```

but it outputs

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No resource with given identifier found
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either
                                  by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block,
                                  or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). 
                                  (rejection id: 1)
```

so I tried with

```js
try {
     mainWindow.webContents.debugger.attach('1.3')
} catch (err) {
     console.log('Debugger attach failed: ', err)
}

mainWindow.webContents.debugger.on('detach', (event, reason) => {
     console.log('Debugger detached due to: ', reason)
});

mainWindow.webContents.debugger.sendCommand('Network.enable');

mainWindow.webContents.debugger.on('message', function(event, method, params, resourceType){
     if (method === 'Network.responseReceived') {
          if (params.type === 'XHR') {
               mainWindow.webContents.debugger.sendCommand('Network.getResponseBody', { requestId: params.requestId }, function (body, body64) {
                    console.log(body);
               });
          }
     }
});
```

but it outputs the same:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No resource with given identifier found
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either
                                  by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block,
                                  or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). 
                                  (rejection id: 1)
```

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been a while since I wrote that question, and I just found the solution to it.
I was mixing the WebRequest API and the Debugger API, which don't share the same id for the requests. I also put a function as an argument, however the sendMessage method returns a promise and does not have a callback function.

Here is an approach using just the Debugger API which works just fine:

```js
try {
  mainWindow.webContents.debugger.attach('1.3');
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Debugger attach failed: ', err);
}

mainWindow.webContents.debugger.on('detach', (event, reason) => {
  console.log('Debugger detached due to: ', reason);
});

mainWindow.webContents.debugger.on('message', (event, method, params) => {
  if (method === 'Network.responseReceived') {
    console.log(params.response.url);
    mainWindow.webContents.debugger.sendCommand('Network.getResponseBody', { requestId: params.requestId }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
})
  
mainWindow.webContents.debugger.sendCommand('Network.enable');
```

Made using the following examples:

- https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/debugger
- [Chrome Extension - How to get HTTP Response Body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534771/chrome-extension-how-to-get-http-response-body)

Answer (score 1):

To intercept `response` with `body` (for requests originated from `renderer` processes) you can you use:

1. intercepting proxy server (like `mitm-proxy` or `hoxy` or you can write it yourself using `http`, `https`, `http2` or `net` modules). You can run it in the `main` process or in some forked child process
2. browser extension that will intercept all requests in `renderer` process using chromium extensions API

In our product we use heavily modified `hoxy` with `http2` support. But we are considering to rewrite it from the start and add `extension` mode for it.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using a Chromium Extension that gets the `body` and sends it to the main process using the `express` server

Comment: I need something like this but I can't get interception to work. Are you willing to hop out to DM's in discord or something?