# How can I get response body / response text in Electron from headers

Tags: node.js, header, electron, response

Now, I know how to get headers, but how to get Response Body/Response Text is not really comprehensible.
I use Electron

```js
details.responseHeaders[""].toString(); // Return an object
```

Do not return the response body, but I must get it from headers, so I searched on different forum and I did not find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue a while ago, you can use electron debugger API to get the response body and the headers, currently webRequest can't get the response body.

Here's the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66675347/13752696

But basically:

```js
try {
  mainWindow.webContents.debugger.attach('1.3');
} catch (err) { 
 console.log('Debugger attach failed: ', err);
} 

mainWindow.webContents.debugger.on('detach', (event, reason) => { 
  console.log('Debugger detached due to: ', reason);
});

mainWindow.webContents.debugger.on('message', (event, method, params) => {
  if (method === 'Network.responseReceived') { 
    console.log(params.response.url); 
     mainWindow.webContents.debugger.sendCommand('Network.getResponseBody', { requestId: params.requestId }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
});

mainWindow.webContents.debugger.sendCommand('Network.enable');
```