# Intercepting requests in chrome extension with manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I see that there is no way to inspect the body with `declarativeNetRequest`.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration-checklist/ indicates I should replace `webRequestBlocking` with `declarativeNetRequest` permission. But it doesn’t say that `chrome.webRequest` API is deprecated in v3 (it looks like it is) or how long will it continue to work with manifest v2.

Should I stick with manifest v2 even though I don’t know how long it will last?
Google says they made this change for privacy reasons but I don’t see them removing content scripts...

Comment: chrome.webRequest is not deprecated but it can't use `blocking` mode, which shouldn't be necessary to see the body.

Comment: Hm, all details objects are missing any kidnd of response body. Even when there is a non-null content length response header and type text/html, there is no body property. Notice the list of properties on the details object on this documentation page, when using onHeadersReceived here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onHeadersReceived

Comment: You should probably add [MCVE](/help/mcve) because `body` is present only on outgoing requests in MV2, specifically `requestBody`.

Comment: Oh, I am trying to get a response body, I guess this can't be done then. Will try to come up with MCVE.

Comment: It was never possible so we had to use workarounds, see [Chrome Extension - How to get HTTP Response Body?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18534771)