# Chrome Extension - Monitoring network traffic with body data in background

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I want to monitor the network traffic from background.js (or content script) on any page with response body data.
I tried these before:
  chrome.devtools.network which allows us to monitor the network only when devtool is open. (I need to do this in background or maybe injected script)

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener((request) => {
   if (request.response) {
       console.log(request.response);
   }
});
```

chrome.webRequest which gives us limited information about requests without their bodies.

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener((details) => {
     console.log(details);
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}
);
```

I also checked this
  [Chrome Extension - How to get HTTP Response Body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534771/chrome-extension-how-to-get-http-response-body)

but it shows the debug tip at least one time on the screen.

Is it not possible for security or some other reason or is it possible to somehow observe the network traffic with the response body?