# Get network data in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, network-tools

I have a chrome extenison but i can't figure out how to access the data in the devtools network tab and send to the popup. Any suggestion?
it's basically a bug reporting chrome extension where you can take screenshots, create issue, and I need the network log (and/or console)

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "my-chrome-extension",
  "description": "Chrome Extension for report bug",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "./icon.png",
    "36": "./icon.png",
    "48": "./icon.png",
    "120": "./icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "js/vendor.js", "js/content_script.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "inject-script.js",
    "js/inject-script.js"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "PerfWatch"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You cant access it directly. Only via API like with webRequest via bg script.
Example:

`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener((details) => {
  if(details.url.indexOf("Target") && details.method === "OPTIONS/..." && details.initiator.indexOf("Source"){
   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(details.tabId, {
       message: "xyz"
      });
    }
  })`

Comment: @Red_Baron Thank for the answer. In bg script the "chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener" never get called :/

Answer (score 0):

You cant access it directly. Only via API like webRequest via bg script.

Example:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener((details) => {
     //This identifies a redirect to another page
    if (details.url.indexOf("Target") && details.method === "OPTIONS/..." && details.initiator.indexOf("Source")) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(details.tabId, {
            message: "xyz"
        });
    }
})
```

Your manifest.json must include the webRequest permission in order to access the webRequests:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "my-chrome-extension",
  "description": "Chrome Extension for report bug",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "./icon.png",
    "36": "./icon.png",
    "48": "./icon.png",
    "120": "./icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "js/vendor.js", "js/content_script.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "inject-script.js",
    "js/inject-script.js"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "PerfWatch"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "webRequest"
  ]
}
```

**Hint:**
There are additional APIs like `webNavigation` and `webRequestBlocking` if you need more funtionallity.

Comment: Yes, I had gave the permissions, sorry for not mentioning. Same problem

Comment: Which details do you need exactly - "details from network tab" could be many. Do you have your desired URLs within the webRequest?

Comment: I need all response on all url and access to this data in the popup. I tried this filter {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}  (I will need onCompleted instead of onBeforeRequest probably)

Comment: Then its a possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534771/chrome-extension-how-to-get-http-response-body

Comment: it's possible, thanks