# How can I get the packets that are being sent in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, request, sniffing

I need to get a packet's headers (as you would in devtools with rightclick and copy as fetch) and send it again. How can I do that in a chrome extension??? Any help is appreciated. The packet is xhr and called typing.

Comment: I feel like chrome.declarativeNetRequest can be used.

Comment: declarativeNetRequest can't be used. You can use chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived in background script or [XHR/fetch spoofing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71012727/) in page context.