# Chrome Request does not show POST response visible via CURL

Tags: google-chrome, curl, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension where I make a POST request to my server. When I make the post request via curl I can see (via the command line) the json response. However, when I make the same request via the extension, I cannot see the response. I tried researching what might be causing it ([Chrome Extension - How to get HTTP Response Body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534771/chrome-extension-how-to-get-http-response-body)) but I am still not sure the root cause. Does anyone know what configuration (or other detail) might be blocking the response in chrome but not curl?