# get request and response body from Chrome API onCompleted method

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to record request and response body, chrome API `onCompleted` method is giving to record response header. How to do without opening developer tool?

I am developing a Chrome extension where I should capture total request and response. Currently, for the response, I'm able to capture response headers alone, is there a way to capture the entire response body? I have looked all the Chrome APIs and include `onComplete` method it is giving the option to capture response header only. Also, I want to capture this response body without opening the developer tools.

```js
function recordData() {
  chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(recordStatus) {
    console.log("Recording Data" + recordStatus);
  }, {
    urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }, ["responseHeaders"]);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I am developing a chrome extension where I should capture total request and response, currently, for the response, I'm able to capture response headers alone, is there a way to capture the entire response body?. I have looked all the chrome APIs and include onComplete method it is giving the option to capture response header only. Also, I want to capture this response body without opening the developer tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extensions - Other ways to read response bodies than chrome.devtools.network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393638/chrome-extensions-other-ways-to-read-response-bodies-than-chrome-devtools-netw)

Comment: Is there another way to capture Response body apart from Chrome API?

Answer (score 1):

<del>I use a simple way to control this. Based on field `requestId` of both request and response.</del>

<del>Create a global Map, when event request header arrive, put it into the map with key `requestId`. remember to remove it from the map when finished, or your background page may crash as `Out of Memory`.</del>

[Chrome extensions - Other ways to read response bodies than chrome.devtools.network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393638/chrome-extensions-other-ways-to-read-response-bodies-than-chrome-devtools-netw)

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing, at the moment I see that it is only possible with other browsers like Firefox.

[webRequest.filterResponseData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/filterResponseData)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35194215)

Answer (score -1):

You are using the wrong webRequest.

The **onCompleted** listener fires at the very end (it’s the very last one) so it’s only useful to monitor when there’s a "sneaky" URL change without a page-refresh, as happens when watching different U-tube videos.

But if what you want (as I understand you) is to catch the Request and Response headers exchanged between a server and the browser, then you have to use these two listeners:

```
var Log1='';  // Let's save all REQUEST headers in this string.


chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){

 Log1 = details.requestId +' - '+ details.method +' - '+ details.frameId +' - '+ details.type +' - '+ details.url +'<br>'+ Log1;

},{urls:['<all_urls>']},['blocking','requestHeaders']);




var Log2='';  // Let's save all RESPONSE headers in this string.


chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details){

 let D=details.responseHeaders;

 for(var i=0; i<D.length; i++){

  Log2 = D[i].name +' - '+ D[i].value + '<br>' + Log2;

 }

},{urls:['<all_urls>']},['blocking','responseHeaders']);
```

**NB:** In the first listener I'm only saving the interesting parts but you can always use a loop to catch *everything* like in the listener below.

Catching everything means that you get a repeat of the User Agent and all other repetitive boring headers.

I know I'm late on the scene for your needs but maybe someone else needs all this.