# Electron how to intercept http response body

Tags: electron

Is there some way to intercept `BrowserWindow` http response body in main process without debugger?

Is it impossible to use `WebRequest` class and `onCompleted` method?

I can do that with debugger but for some reason I can not use this

```js
await w.webContents.debugger.sendCommand('Network.enable')
  w.webContents.debugger.on('message', async (event, method, params) => {
    if (method === 'Network.dataReceived') {
      const responseBody = await w.webContents.debugger.sendCommand('Network.getResponseBody', {requestId: params.requestId})
    }
  })
```

**UPD**

I found only one solution expect `debugger`. It is not perfect  but it solve my issue.

Use `webPreference.preload` to inject this monkey patching script.

```js
let oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
 this.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('data: ' + this.responseText);
 });

 return oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

`console.log` may be replaced with ipc to send this data to main process

Comment: does it work if you use `debugger`? I tried both `Fetch` and `Network`, but `w.webContents.debugger.sendCommand('Network.getResponseBody', {requestId: params.requestId}, (...args) => {console.log(...args)})` never returns anything in Electron (but works in a Chrome Extension). Chrome webRequest API cannot get the response body (that's probably the same for Electron).

Comment: With webRequest you could probably redirect the request to a local file (at least it works in a Chrome Extension like this `return {redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("modifiedFile.js")}`).

Comment: @Sentero-esp12 it's does not solve my problem

Comment: To use debugger you need call `...debugger.attach("1.1")` before

Comment: Yes, i'm attaching the debugger, but it still doesn't work. I've created an issue here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23594
And why cannot you use the debugger? Do you want first to intercept the response body and then modify it?

Comment: Also maybe this can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336167/get-request-and-response-body-from-chrome-api-oncompleted-method

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534771/chrome-extension-how-to-get-http-response-body

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, can you create minimal, reproducible example with your code and share link?

Comment: Here is an example to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/Sentero-esp12/reproduce-fetch-network 
For both Fetch and Network domains