# Electron access request/response body and headers from window

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an application that opens various websites in separate electron windows. I need to parse any AJAX request the sites make, in the main thread. Basically access the information that would be shown in the chrome network tab of the dev tools.

I think I can use the `window.webContents` [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents) but can't seem to find the right function in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WebRequest](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-request/) to do this

```js
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })
win.loadURL('YOUR_URL')

const webRequest = win.webContents.session.webRequest

// use webRequest to intercept requests
```

Comment: Any idea how I can get the response body out of that? The listener objects seem to only give the headers and other info.

Comment: @Rafael if you want to access the response body, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61789895/9698583) and the comments on it. Hope it helps